# How to keep displaying results in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SSMS clear results page in the start of execution of a new query. How to disable this feature? 
I want to display all results as a list. Is it possible to configure it in SSMS?

Comment: Run all the queries, not just the one you want, and it'll display them all. For example: `SELECT 1; SELECT 2;` will show 2 results in the results panel. The Results panel only persists until another query is run.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm asking about one-by-one (one after another) running.

Comment: That isn't how SSMS works, no. If you want to retain the data after execution you'll need to export it to something else before running the next query.

Comment: Oh, thx. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with query like that:

```
waitfor delay '00:00:01' --Change delay - or delete it if you don't need it
select getdate() --Change this to your query
go 5 -- change the 5 to different number - if you want to loop it X times
```